# Check if all letter is uppercase or lowercase python, if there is one word in string is different print none

Tags: python, uppercase, lowercase

For input string **S**, print *UPPER* if string **S** contains only uppercase characters (may contain spaces), *LOWER* if string **S** contains only lowercase characters (may contain spaces), otherwise print out *NONE*.

**so here is my code**

```py
test_str = input()

  
res = "LOWER"
for ele in test_str:
  
    # checking for uppercase character and flagging
    if ele.isupper():
        res = "UPPER"
        break

print(str(res))
```

But if a word is neither lowercase nor uppercase, it doesn't None. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for loops here. Just simply use the functions `isupper()` and `islower()` in an `if`-`elif` block, and add an `else` block to take care of mixed case (i.e., print out `None` or `NONE`), like so:

```py
test_str = input()
    
if test_str.isupper():
    print('UPPER')
elif test_str.islower():
    print('LOWER')
else:
    print(None) # or print('NONE')
```

Example input/output:

```
HELLO USER
UPPER

HELLO UsER    
None 

hello user  
LOWER

hello User
None
```

---

Active reading: [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/isupper-islower-lower-upper-python-applications/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Justin contains the key information needed to understand how to do what you want.

For variety, here is an alternative strategy for getting the result your question specified (I have assumed you want the string 'NONE' for mixed case as specified in your question, rather than the Python `None` value).

```py
a = "ABC DEF"
b = "abc def"
c = "abc deF"
def foo(s):
    return ('NONE', 'UPPER', 'LOWER')[1 * s.isupper() + 2 * s.islower()]
print(foo(a),':',a)
print(foo(b),':',b)
print(foo(c),':',c)
```

Output:

```
UPPER : ABC DEF
LOWER : abc def
NONE : abc deF
```